# Impossible to keep user install in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, installer, version

I'm using Windows 11 and I've found that for VS Code, user installer, incredibly, doesn't have the option to check for updates, and it does not do that automatically either (although I've got this configured in the settings).

I used the system installer but somehow, after a day or so, the installation comes back to the user setup, hiding the "Check for updates" option from the *Help* menu.

It has happened twice already, last time yesterday: **I installed the system setup (v1.79), and today the one being executed has the user setup (v1.76).**

To avoid losing any information, I install directly the system installer over the user installer (so, I don't uninstall and install, but I install it directly).

How is it possible? **How can I execute one day the system installer and the next day, executing it from the same access, it switches to user setup?** Is there anyway to install the user setup without losing all extensions and data from previous installation?

I guess the issue lies in the directory which is being executed from, but **I execute the program always clicking the icon in the taskbar**, and I pinned the system setup instance icon yesterday.

Thank you.

Comment: Was the original installation done as Administrator, and later VS Code use as a a user?

Comment: Both installations were done as Administrator. Even then, I don't understand why the first executions were getting the system setup, as intended, but after a while it switched back to the user setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I went to uninstall VS Code completely to fresh install a System setup, and I saw in the Windows program manager that I had both instances installed (user and system).

The reason why, even though I pinned the System instance to the taskbar, it was executing the User instance is unknown to me, but uninstalling the User instance from the program manager from Windows solved this issue.